# Does cloudfoundry support grails apps compiled against java 1.7?

Tags: grails, java-7, cloud-foundry

When I try to deploy my java 1.7 based Grails app to cloudfoundry, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: grails/plugin/cache/CacheConfigArtefactHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class grails.plugin.cache.CacheConfigArtefactHandler)
```

I thought that I read somewhere that this is now supported?

```
Detected a Java SpringSource Grails Application, is this correct? [Yn]:
Application Deployed URL [my-project.cloudfoundry.com]:
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [512M]:
How many instances? [1]:
Bind existing services to 'my-project'? [yN]: y
1: rabbitmq-67ae5
Which one?: 1
Create services to bind to 'my-project'? [yN]:
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]:
Creating Application: OK
Binding Service [rabbitmq-67ae5]: OK
Uploading Application:
Checking for available resources: OK
Processing resources: OK
Packing application: OK
Uploading (20K): OK
Push Status: OK
Staging Application 'my-project': OK
Starting Application 'my-project': ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you need to remember to specify the runtime when you deploy;

vmc push my_app --runtime=java7